# FullCalendar V2 | V3 - Restringir la seleccion a un solo cuadro

Tags: select, fullcalendar

Buenas, una ayuda por favor, estoy usando el plugin jquery FULLCALENDAR. Y mediante la documentación he logrado realizar algunas adecuaciones para mi uso.

Lo que no he podido es por Ejemplo: Que si tengo configurado el calendario para que aparezca cada cuadro a 1 Hora, en si el cliente puede seleccionar 2 cuadros, osea 2 horas.

Y lo que quiero restringir es que solo sea seleccionable un cuadro (1 hora).

Si pueden ayudarme por favor. Estoy usando la Version 2 y 3 del FullCalendar.